# Mono - form does not display until application finishes running

Tags: mono

I have a C# application that is working in production, that we are now trying to run on the Mac using Mono.  The program compiles into a single executable, no extra DLLs.  It displays a single window, and then starts downloading files, displaying the status of each file as it does so. It works fine as a standalone program, but when I run it under Mono (on Windows), the Main Form Window does not appear until all of the files are downloaded.

I have tried the following code at the start of the form (OnLoad Event), but nothing makes a difference:

```
private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    this.Show();
    this.BringToFront();
    this.Focus();
    this.Select();
    this.Refresh();
    Application.Doevents();
    ...
```

Any thoughts on why this should work fine in C# but not in Mono Windows?  It also does the same behavior on the Mac, so it is not exclusively a windows problem.

Thanks, Neil

Comment: Make sure you do not start your downloading until the form is shown. You are tying up the main thread. Please  show where you start your file download.

Comment: The file download starts at the "...".  This works fine in .net as the DoEvents allows the form to finish displaying.  Does not work in Mono for the reasons you stated.  I am trying to avoid using a timer and having to re-write a lot of code to handle displaying to the form between threads.

Comment: Actually using Application.DoEvents is justing masking the problem and is not recommended, I have used it in the past and it can be quite painful trying to find why code is locking up. My recommendation would be to create a One-Shot timer start it at the end of your OnLoad Eventhandler, as soon as it fires disable the timer and run your download code. Your other option would be to put your code in your forms shown event.

Comment: Mark, spent part of today rewriting to use a Background Worker process.  Which was actually kind of cool - had not used one before and it did the job very nicely.  The thing that makes it better than just using a thread or a timer is that the background worker events actually get delivered in the thread of the UI.  This means I don't have to do a bunch of checking for InvokeRequired and creating delegates so it makes running background threads which interact with the UI much easier.  Also, seems to be a lightweight thread.  Thanks for your original point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Events do not work in the Mono Framework.  The application was designed to run and immediately start downloading, while showing the status of the downloads in the main form.  This works fine in .net, but not in Mono.  The workaround is to use the excellent Background Worker component, which was present in .Net Framework 2.0.  It has mechanisms for reporting progress back to the parent thread which don't require using InvokeRequired.  Thanks to Mark Hall for pointing out the original design flaw in the code.